# How do I get a back button in pushed ViewController (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a `viewController` with a menu button set as `navigationItem` like this:

`self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftButton, animated: false)`.

It brings up a drawer menu, which is fine in its context. But what if I want to push the `viewController` from elsewhere in the project where a back button is more appropriate instead of a menu button? That is, I just want to go back to the previous `viewController` instead of bringing up the menu. How do I get rid of the menu button and instead get the back button in that particular instance?

Here is the code for the class. As you can see, the `navigationItem` is set here.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setUserInterfaceStyleLight()
    loginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardOne", bundle: nil)
    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu-icon"), style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(self.leftSideMenuButtonPressed(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftButton, animated: false)

    self.segmentController.tintColor = .white
    if showContacts == true {
        lastSegmentViewed = 1
    }

    Analytics.logEvent("contact_book", parameters: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userDidLogin(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UserDidLogin, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationAndViewWasResumed(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
    self.view.backgroundColor = ThemTemplate.shared.getThem().secondaryColor

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        segmentController.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    } else {

        segmentController.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

Is it possible to hide and disable the `navigationItem` from the previous `viewController` or change it to a back button?

This is how I push the `viewController`:

```
UIStoryboard *containerStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
BaseViewController *v = [containerStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"base"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];
```

In the class before the push to the new `viewController` I tried something like:

```
v.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
v.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
```

...which did nothing (and yes, setting it to nil is dumb, just wanted to see if something happened and it did not).

The `viewController` I'm pushing from is not embedded in a navigationController, if that helps. I tried embedding it on one, but with the same results.

Left me know if there is anything else that can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Bool var in `BaseViewController`:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var bShowMenu: Bool = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setUserInterfaceStyleLight()
        loginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardOne", bundle: nil)

        if bShowMenu {
            let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu-icon"), style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(self.leftSideMenuButtonPressed(_:)))
            self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftButton, animated: false)
        }

        self.segmentController.tintColor = .white
        if showContacts == true {
            lastSegmentViewed = 1
        }

        Analytics.logEvent("contact_book", parameters: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userDidLogin(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UserDidLogin, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationAndViewWasResumed(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
        self.view.backgroundColor = ThemTemplate.shared.getThem().secondaryColor

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            segmentController.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        } else {

            segmentController.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}
```

then, when you instantiate the controller, tell it whether or not to use the "menu" button:

```
UIStoryboard *containerStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
BaseViewController *v = [containerStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"base"];

// if you do NOT want the menu button
v.bShowMenu = false

[self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];
```